Minimizing the ratio of sum of all possible distances between 4 points and the minimum distance.
Please solve the following problem from the Chinese Mathematical Olympiad 2002.

Let $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ be 4 points on the plane. Find the minimum value of $$\displaystyle \dfrac{\sum_{1\leq i <j\leq 4} P_iP_j}{\min_{1\leq i<j\leq 4} P_iP_j}.$$

We suspect the answer is $5+\sqrt{3},$ which is achieved when $P_3, P_4$ are intersections of the circles with $P_1, P_2$ as centres and $P_1P_2$ as radius.
We have a hand-wavy argument with many cases. The basic idea is to fix a minimum distance $P_1P_2$ and then move $P_3, P_4$ while preserving the minimum.

Who are we and why is this "suspicion"? YOU should know the rules!

We=isomorphism and frankly irrelevant mathematically.
If we knew how to prove it, I wont be asking it here!
Also the problem is from a well known olympiad and a proof is not available on the internet as far as I can search. So any discussion here adds value.

Our suspicion simply stems from the fact that those two are natural pair of points that arise. We do not have any stronger reasons. If we fix the minimum distance P1P2, then we are not sure if P3 and P4 have to be on opposite sides for the optimal answer.

Did you tested your idea?

Without loss of generality, by scaling if needed, we can assume that the min distance is $1$. Then the problem boils down to

minimising the sum of distances provided the min distance is $1$.

This is exactly the problem considered in this question. And the answer is that the sum of distances is minimised when the points are arranged in a rhombus of side $1$ and one of the internal angles $60^\circ$, exactly as expected by the OP. Therefore, as the OP suspected, the minimum value of the given ratio is $5+\sqrt3$.
